# Operations of Tensors with Different Orders

Tags: tensor-calculus

I know that a 4th order tensor times a 2nd order tensor yields a 2nd order tensor; and a 2nd order tensor times a 2nd order tensor yields a 0th order tensor, or scalar. But from my linear algebra knowledge, the product of two 3 by 3 matrices is still a 3 by 3 matrix, which indicates that the product of two second-order tensors is still a second order tensor. How do I reconcile these things?

Comment: What operation do you mean by "times"? You are mixing different meanings of the same word.

Comment: $A^{\mu\nu}B^{\rho \eta}=C^{\mu \nu \rho \eta}$ clearly these two second order tensors resulted in a fourth order tensor, so you can see how you have to specify what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank of a tensor should not be confused with the dimension of a matrix. All matrices are second order tensors with (rank = 2) regardless of their dimension. In terms of tensor notation, a matrix $M$ is represented as $M_{ab}$ where the two indices $a$ and $b$ represent the rows and columns. These indices run over all the integer values that represent the different rows and columns.

Moreover, a "4th order tensor times a 2nd order tensor yields a 2nd order tensor," *only if two of the indices are contracted*. Compare
$$ A_{abcd}B_{cd} = C_{ab} , $$
and
$$ A_{abcd}B_{de} = C_{abce} . $$
In the first case two indices are contracted leading to a second rank tensor. In the second case only one index is contracted leading to a 4th rank tensor.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Could you show me how the two tensor products would look like in coordinate-free notations?

Comment: What do you mean by "coordinate-free notation"?

Comment: I mean the notation without using indices and use tensor notations.